# Append Handlebars fragment to div with jquery

Tags: jquery, append, handlebars.js

I have some handlebars template code that I'm trying to append to a div, that also includes other HTML. I believe I'm simply missing a single/double quote somewhere, but can't pin it down:

```
$("dd:contains('STORY')")
  .parents('.col-xs-6')
  .find('.well-sm')
  .css("background", "#ffb347")
  .append('<div class="badge type">STORY</div>'{{#each data.videoJason.entity.stream.timeline}}'<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="www.url.com/&#123;&#123;&#123;entityProps.uuid&#125;&#125;&#125;" data-layout="button"></div>'{{/each}}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the single quotes at the starting of template.. everything should be a string like this

```
.append('<div class="badge type">STORY</div>{{#each data.videoJason.entity.stream.timeline}}<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="www.url.com/&#123;&#123;&#123;entityProps.uuid&#125;&#125;&#125;" data-layout="button"></div>{{/each}}');
```

Comment: I had to revise and simplify the URL, and no longer using Facebook sharing. The issue now is how to apply the URL so that it doesn't put all the links into each of the locations that this link is placed. Each link should have its own unique URL applied.

`{{#each data.videoJason.entity.stream.timeline}}<a href="http://url.com/{{entityProps.uuid}}">Share</a>{{/each}}`

Comment: I didn't get ur point.. Can u elaborate on that pls ? Also ur template in comment looks ok to me, wat is the issue ?